# GoLang os.Chdir() permission denied

Tags: file, go, directory, permissions

I am writing a program that creates a directory and then changes the working directory to the newly created directorty in order to do some work:

```
func main() {
    err := os.Mkdir("English", 0777) // I know 777 is not good practice, first I want to get Chdir() working
    if err != nil && !os.IsExist(err) {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = os.Chdir("English")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
023/02/05 18:15:45 chdir English: permission denied
exit status 1
```

Comment: Check the error from the Mkdir call, regardless of IsExist. If the directory is there already, check the existing permissions.

Comment: @JimB the only error associated with the call to `Mkdir()` is that the directory exists. Checking the created directory in my terminal, I can see that it was created, and has `drw-r--r--` permissions when I execute `ls -l.

Comment: So the directory already exists and has the wrong permissions

Comment: To be clear, the directory did not exist until my program ran the first time.  Deleting the directory and re-running the program results in the directory being recreated with incorrect permissions, despite specifying 0777.

Comment: Then it appears you have an incorrect umask or filesystem settings preventing the setting of the execute bits by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix: executing the program using `sudo` resulted in the directoy being created with permissions as specified.